# Count appearances of two-adjacent-cell value in range (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, countif

I am working on a sports analytics tracker in Excel, and for one part I need to **count** (I know there are other questions that just need to find them) how many appearances there are of a two-cell value in a certain range. So, for example, if I was searching for:

```
-----------------
|  foo  |  bar  |
-----------------
```

in:

```
-----------------
|  foo  |  bar  |
-----------------
|  far  |  foo  |
-----------------
|  far  |  fob  |
-----------------
|  foo  |  bar  |
-----------------
|  boo  |  bar  |
-----------------
|  far  |  foo  |
-----------------
|  foo  |  bar  |
-----------------
```

I would like the result to be 3, as the query appears three times. I would like to use a formula for this: I have tried using `COUNTIF`, and while I was able to count up how many matched in each column, I couldn't see how many matched the two-cell combination.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="foo")*(B:B="bar"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what COUNTIFS is for:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"foo",B:B,"bar")
```